# Java call web service issue - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, web, service, jersey

I get an error when I call the service. I tried every solution I could find

Full text of the error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] in context with path [/sove] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.useNamespace(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:63)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.hasSerializeURIAction(AttributeProperty.java:96)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.link(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:232)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:348)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:259)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:251)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:218)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:185)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:163)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:664)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:421)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:411)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have a jax-rs web service like:

```
@GET
@Path("/getAnalyzedMatches")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public static AnalyzeResponseModel getAnalyzedMatches() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    AnalyzeResponseModel response = new AnalyzeResponseModel();
    List<AnalyseResultModel> analyzedMatches = SoveMatchesUtil.getAnalyzedMatches();
    /* try to set object */
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AnalyseResultModel item : analyzedMatches) {
        objectList.add(item);
    }
    response.setList(objectList);
    return response;
}
```

Here is my Response Model:

```
package com.sove.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "list")
public class AnalyzeResponseModel {
    List<Object> list;

    public AnalyzeResponseModel() {
    }

    public List<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sove</groupId>
<artifactId>sove</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lucee/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.3-606.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>sove</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.sove.service</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by making public attributes to private in the response model(AnalyseResultModel).